# how do I check for this combination

Tags: python, regex

I have to check if the given string has a particular combination of characters .
the string should contain (in regexp):-

```
(.*)->(.*)
```

But the problem is that I want at least one default character on both the sides of the arrow i.e `'->'`
Examples :-

```
('a->b') ---> True
('->b') ---> False
('a->') ---> False
('->') ---> False
```

Comment: Is it actually `('a'->'b')` or `a->b`?

Comment: Sorry for that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that there must be at least one character beside of `->` , its what that `+` is for, so you can use the following pattern :

```
r'.+->.+'
```

*Note* that `*` will match zero or more character! for better understanding look at the following diagrams :

```
.+->.+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AzcFT2hkzI9w2LEA)

```
.*->.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can use grouping for your patterns too but based on your [regex function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) the result could be different, also you can use `?`.

another solutions :

```
r'(.+->.+)'
r'(.+)->(.+)'
r'.+?->.+?'
```

> `+?` match between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, **expanding as needed**.
>
> `+` match between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, **giving back as needed**.

Also as mentioned in comment `.+` will match any character,like whitespaces, if you don't such things you can use `\w` (match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
) or `\s` (\S match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`)

Comment: There has to be a ? in there.

Comment: This will also match an empty space `' ->b'`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i'll add an explain about that too!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Maybe OP doesn't have any problem with that, but any way i'll mention it too!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with:

```
(.+)->(.+)
```

or

```
(.{1,})->(.{1,})
```

`{1,}` ... Means minimum 1 times maximum infinity times.